# Binding a property from a html element to another html element with knockoutjs

Tags: knockout.js

I WPF it is called element binding when I want to bind the property of a control to another controls property.

What binding do I have to take using knockoutjs?

And how would I do the element to element binding?

I want that both divs in times and total have the same width.

The width in total is already an observable maybe I just need to reference the total width but I guess this would happen with an "element binding" ?

Or is it only possible with knockout to bind a html element to any property of the viewmodel in the context? Because that would mean my viewmodel must have 2 properties time(s) and total and while enumerating/binding them in the view I just reference the common width property of this viewmodel.

```
<div id="times">
    <div>
        <div style="width:OfTotalDiv"></div>        
    </div>
    <div id="title"></div>
</div>
<div id="total">
    <div>
        <div style="width:100px"></div>     
    </div>
    <div id="title"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you need data-binding for this? You could probably do this with css classes.

```html
<style type="text/css">
    .small-boxes .this-box { width: 100px; }
    .large-boxes .this-box { width: 200px; }
</style>

<body class="small-boxes">
    <div id="times">
        <div>
            <div class="this-box"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="total">
        <div>
            <div class="this-box"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

```js
$('body').toggleClass('small-boxes large-boxes');
```

---

If you really need binding, you could do something like this:

```html
<div id="times">
    <div>
        <div data-bind="style: { width: widthOfTotal }"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="total">
    <div>
        <div data-bind="style: { width: widthOfTotal }"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the view-model:

```js
self.widthOfTotal = ko.observable('100px');
```

Comment: shit... sorry man I did mean height not width! The height of the total divs are computed in the viewmodel. So I need to reference the height of the single divs from the times div.

Comment: and I can not bind the width of all divs within times div because this area is mapped to another variable of the viewmodel.

Comment: You could use the [jQuery resize plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-resize-plugin/) to poll for size changes, and update an observable when the event is triggered.

Comment: style binding the width in a foreach would only work if I can iterate both arrarys with one foreach binding in the html but I cant so I computed everything in the viewmodel :) Generally you are correct because I gave you too less information.